# A closed form of $\int_0^1{\dfrac{1-x}{\log x}(x+x^2+x^{2^2}+x^{2^3}+\cdots)}\:dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I need some hint to calculate this integral

> $$\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{1-x}{\log x}\left(x+x^{2}+x^{2^2}+x^{2^3}+\cdots\right)}{\rm d} x$$

Regards!

Answer (score 12):

We have

> $$
> \int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{1-x}{\log x}(x+x^{2}+x^{2^{2}}+x^{2^{3}}+\cdots)}\:dx=-\log 3. \tag1
> $$

*Proof*. One may recall that, using [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html), we have
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{a-1}-x^{b-1}}{\log x}\:dx=\log\frac ab \quad (a,b>0). \tag2
$$
Considering a *finite sum* in the integrand, we get
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{1-x}{\log(x)}(x+x^{2}+x^{2^{2}}+\cdots+x^{2^N})}\:dx\qquad  (N=0,1,2,\cdots)
\\\\&=\sum_{n=0}^N\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2^n}-x^{2^n+1}}{\log x}\:dx\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N\log\frac{2^n+1}{2^n+2}\qquad \quad (\text{using}\, (2))\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N\left(\log(2^n+1)-\log(2^{n-1}+1)-\log 2\right) \quad(\text{a telescoping sum})\\\\
&=\log(2^N+1)-\log(2^{-1}+1)-(N+1)\log 2\\\\
&=-\log 3+\log\left(1+1/2^N\right),
\end{align}
$$ then, letting $N \to+\infty$, leads to $(1)$.

**Remark**. One may see that we can generalize $(1)$.

Comment: Voted up. Nice solution!

Comment: @NimaBavari Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm out of practice doing calculations for long, long years, so it's probably my fault, but I can't see how you get the last equation in your computation. Where does the minus sign for $\operatorname{log} 3$ come from?

Comment: @OlivierOloa as I told, I'm out of practice, but now at least the last step is exactly what I get from the previous.

Comment: @OlivierOloa It looks like the original mistake was somewhere in the transform of your cited form of Frullani's integral ($\int_0^\infty$) to your formula (2). I checked, and after several mistakes of my own, after substituting $x=e^u$ and then $u=-v$ and changing the integration boundaries and signs, it now looks correct.  I wonder if there isn't a tool to do such things nowadays.

Comment: @asdasd-asd Are you OK with my answer? Thanks.